# JQuery UI - Dialog doesn't drag correctly with expanable DIVs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

My site basically has 7 expandable DIVs that the user expands and closes.

At the end of the page is a submit button linking to a JQuery dialog box which confirms the submit basically.

What happens is that the JQuery Dialog box jumps down, often appearing to have disappeared which makes the user unable to submit the form. The amount it jumps down depends on the size of the DIVs that expand.

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ltw78/1/

**HTML:**

```
<p>1. Click "Submit" to get the dialog box to appear, drag it around and you will notice it works normally. Close the dialog box after. </p>
<div id="clickme">2. Click here to expand the first box.</div>
<div id="clickme2">3. Click here to expand the second box</div>
<p>4. Scroll down to the submit button and click "Submit" again to get the dialog to appear. Now drag it around, and you will notice it jumps down the page quite a bit.  </p>
<div id="movingDiv">Some content
    <br />Some content
    <br />Some content
    <br />Some content
    <br />
</div>
<div id="movingDiv2">More content
    <br/>More content
    <br/>More content
    <br/>More content</div>
<div id="dialog" title="You have clicked submit. You now have two choices:">
    <p class="black">1) Do you want to submit this form as a new Booking for feedback services?
        <br />Then click <u>Submit.</u>

    </p>
    <p class="black">2) Do you want to submit this form as an amendment to a previous Booking Form submitted?
        <br />Then click <u>Overwrite.</u>

    </p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="formbutton submitbutton" />
```

**JS:**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth: 550,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Overwrite",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $('#Overwrite').submit();
        }
    }, {
        text: "Submit",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $('#Submit').submit();
        }
    }]

});
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
});

$("#clickme").click(function () {
    $("#movingDiv").slideDown("slow", function () {

    });
});
$("#clickme2").click(function () {
    $("#movingDiv2").slideDown("slow", function () {

    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#movingDiv, #movingDiv2 {
    height:500px;
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: does it absolutely need to be draggable? because if it's gonna be used just for confirmation doesn't look like the feature is a must http://jsfiddle.net/Ltw78/3/

Comment: It would be the final option to fix the issue. It would be nice to have it dragable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround that keeps the functionality of `draggable`.

The `drag` event keeps track of `CSS position` and an `offset` as well, considering the expansible `divs`, the `CSS position` isn't expecting a change on the parent height, that being said you can still count on the `offset` to set it as true `position`.

First of all we need to initialize the `drag` callback;

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth: 550,
    drag: function( event, ui ) {}, //added line
    buttons: [{
      text: "Overwrite",
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $('#Overwrite').submit();
      }
    }, {
      text: "Submit",
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $('#Submit').submit();
      }
    }]

});
```

After, we bind an event listener, forcing the `position` of the dragged dialog to be the `offset`:

```
$( "#dialog" ).on( "dialogdrag", function( event, ui ) {
  ui.position.top = ui.offset.top
} );
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltw78/4/) here

Comment: Thanks G. I will give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an unfixed bug with the JQuery UI Dialog.

The work around would be to disable dragging using:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ draggable: false });
```